# Statistical test for random graph's edges binomial distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, networkx

I'm exploring random graph behaviour, and want to estimate the edge distribution.

```
l = []
k = 0
while k < 10000:
    g = nx.gnp_random_graph(n=n,p=p)
    l.append(len(g.edges()))
    k += 1
```

Then I plotting the histogram `np.histogram(l, bins=150)` and it the distribution seems to be binomial 
But, I want to apply a statistic test to estimate that.

I tried `scipy.stats.binom_test` but, it requires other parameters. 
How can I estimate distribution, given histogram?

Comment: You can try asking this at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`binom_test`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) can be used to check whether a single Erdos-Renyi graph has a reasonable number of edges for the parameters.  But you are asking about an ensemble of results, and whether these have the right distribution.

For this you can use a goodness of fit test, which compares the empirical distribution to a hypothesised null distribution.  Various GoF tests exist but you need one for discrete data. statsmodels implements the Χ<sup>2</sup> squared test for goodness of fit [(docs)](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/stats.html#goodness-of-fit-tests-and-measures).

We need a null hypothesis to use this type of test, which is a binomial distribution: The E-R graphs have `n*(n-1)/2` possible edges and they are added
with *independent* probability p. It is kind of obvious that this distribution will be binomial, so all you are really doing in this is checking whether the random number generator is ok.

Anyway, our null model is that the distribution of edges is ~`Binom(n_edge, p)`, with an expected number of edges `p * n*(n-1)/2`.

---

Here is code that applies the test.

```
import networkx as nx
from statsmodels.stats import gof
from scipy import stats

# generate some graphs and measure edge count
p = 0.1
n = 100
n_edge = n*(n-1)/2

l = []
for i in xrange(1000):
    g = nx.gnp_random_graph(n=n, p=p)
    l.append(len(g.edges()))

## we use a chi square test of goodness of fit for the measured edge counts
# chi square: null hypothesis is that data l comes from the binom distribution.
# so if pval is > alpha we do not reject the null.

alpha = 0.001 
chi2, pval, sig_test, msg = gof.gof_chisquare_discrete(stats.distributions.binom, (n_edge, p,), l, alpha, msg="Binom ")
print msg
print "\tpval: {:.3f}".format(pval)
print "\tgood fit to binom(N, p)? {}".format(pval > alpha)
```

This produces output like:

```
 >>> chisquare - test for Binom at arg = (4950, 0.1) with pval = 0.8129512780114826 
 >>>    pval: 0.813
 >>>    good fit to binom(N, p)? True
```

So the distribution of edges is indeed binomial.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Could you please clarify, why alpha = 0.001. As far I remember, we reject/accept hypothesis on p-value = 0.005

Comment: Also, I found out, that this approach works bad with large n. Try n = 200, for example.

Comment: regarding alpha, there are lots of discussions about appropriate values for significance (see e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.4120).  A p-value threshold of 0.05, a la Fisher, might be appropriate with 20 samples.  But for 10k samples, a stricter threshold is prudent.  In this case the resulting p-value is 0.8, and so it doesn't really matter what strictness you set, you will always reject it!

Comment: As for the n=200 case, yes I see that now.  I've had a look into it and this is rather unfortunate.  I think it needs a bug report with statsmodels because the error arises from the code that samples the distribution function.  Here: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/stats/gof.py#L211 the limits are set at -1000 and +1000, and then moved in according to the specific data.  With n=100, the relevant part of the PDF is [445, 545] ish.  but n=200, the relevant part goes up to [1890, 2090].  That means that the bins in the range [-1000, 1000] are all empty.

Comment: as a cludge, you can edit the `gof.py` code, increasing the 1000 to 10000 or perhaps 1e6. But the statsmodels developers will be able to comment on whether there are other reasons that the 1000 value is chosen, e.g. due to loss of support of the distribution.

Comment: @Bonlenfum It's a bug. It looks like that threshold and the number of bins are hardcoded for the initial usecase and have never been generalized, especially not for large random variables or large samples.